# Resizing div width to automatically fit paragraph's width

Tags: html

I have a div and within it a paragraph:

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    <p style="color: #FF8000; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana;">
        &ensp;&ensp;This is my first line in the paragraph. This line cannot be broken.<br />
        &ensp;&ensp;This is my second line in the paragraph. This line cannot be broken.<br /><br />
        This is another line within the paragraph. This line cannot be broken.<br />        
    </p>
</div>
```

As seen above, my paragraph has a lot of line. Each line ends with a new line. Some of the end with two new lines.

I would like div's width to be resized automatically to the longest paragraph line width.
How can I do this?

> Note: I do not want lines to be broken into separate lines until 
>  is reached.
>     Div's width must be resized to the longest line width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the display of the div to `inline-block` and to prevent wrapping of lines add `white-space: nowrap;` for the paragraphs:

```
#MyDiv{
    display: inline-block;
}

#MyDiv p{
    white-space: nowrap;    
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LMB6L/6/

Comment: Why lines too long are broken into two? I do not want this. I want lines to be printed as one line and then when <br /> is reached, to jump to the next line.

Comment: it works. One more question, I have another case, where I have this within a jquery tooltip. In that case, my problem is that when using white-space: nowrap; line is out of the jquery tooltip's width. Do you know why?

Comment: Probably has to do with the `overflow` property of the tooltip. Try setting `overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
#MyDiv {outline:1px solid red;display:inline-block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/62CQt/

Comment: see my updated post. I do not want lines to be broken into two lines.

Comment: I saw, and nowrap is the way to go. It's also the reason the text spills out of your tooltip, since it most likely has a fixed width to go with the absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `width:auto;` or `inherit` in the paragraph modification